# How to migrate the physical googlebox to public cloud AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, cloud, googlebot, google-search-appliance

A client of mine has 1000+ websites hosted in private data center. Now they wanted to migrate it on AWS cloud. Among the physical servers they have physical google-box appliance hosted in rack in data center. How to migrate this on AWS cloud? Are there in software replacements possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no virtual GSA available.  It is an appliance only.

If the client requires virtual they would have to look at another solution that provides virtual server installation.

Google is launching a new cloud-friendly solution, in the future, but no date has been given, nor any details.  It is likely this solution would be hosted in the Google cloud though.